# what does this <bound method Stack.pop of <__main__.Stack object at 0x03C74AB0>> mean?

Tags: python-3.x, indexoutofboundsexception, postfix-notation

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
    def push(self,item):
        self.items.append(item)
    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()
    def isEmpty(self):
        return (self.items ==[])
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.items)

def postfixEval(postfixExpres):
         operandStack = Stack()
         tokenlist = postfixExpres.split()

         for token in tokenlist:
           if token in "0123456789":
             operandStack.push(int(token))
           else:
             operand2 = operandStack.pop
             operand1 = operandStack.pop
             result = doMath(token,operand1,operand2)
             operandStack.push(result)
         return operandStack.pop

def doMath(op,op1,op2):
       if op == "*":
        return op1*op2
       elif op == "/":
        return op1/op2
       elif op =="+":
        return op1 + op2
       elif op == "-":
        return op1 - op2

print(postfixEval('12+'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it means you returned a function object of the `pop` method instead of a value at the end of `postfixEval`. Change `operandStack.pop` to `operandStack.pop()` (add the parentheses to apply the `pop` method instead of returning it).

Additionally, if I'm not mistaken, `'12+'.split()` will return `'123'` in python, since `split` uses whitespaces as the default delimiter. If you want to turn the string into a list of single characters, you can cast the string to a list instead `list('12+')` will return `['1', '2', '+']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class stack():
    def __init__(self):
        self.items=[]
    def push(self,item):
        self.items.append(item)
    def pop(self):`
        self.items.pop()
    def get_stack(self):
        return self.items
    def emp(self):
        return self.items==[]
    def peek(self):
        if not self.emp():
            return self.items[-1]

s=stack()
print("stack is empty: ",s.emp())
s.push('a')
s.push('b')
print(s.get_stack())
s.push(12)
print(s.get_stack())
s.pop()
print(s.get_stack())
s.push('c')
print(s.get_stack())
print('peek value is: ',s.peek())
print("stack is empty: ",s.emp())
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case it means you're using the method object instead of calling it. In the `doMath` method you should use both variables like this: `op1()*op2()`.